# Markov matcher for dabbrev

Tags: completion, dabbrev

While writing plain text (not code), I'd like a completion based on more context, an exmple would speak more so here it is:

Given the following buffer (a preloaded big text corpus would make more sense in reality):

```
foo bar baz
foo bar baz
foo bar boo
poo bar bot
```

and then typing:

```
foo bar
```

(followed by a space and M-/) I'd like dabbrev (or something else) to propose, in the following order:

- `baz`, because it appears twice after `foo bar`, so it's the more probable one.
- `boo`, because it appears after `foo bar`
- `bot`, because it appears after `bar`

Currently `dabbrev` would propose `bot` first, as the nearest possible word following `bar`, if I understand correctly.

In other words, I'd like completion based on Markov chains. Does it already exists? Would it be hard to implement?

Comment: I'm able to do something by using `lsp-mode`, and a backend in Python using `pygls` (https://github.com/JulienPalard/po-language-server), but not with dabbrev.